# azure file share access via web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, unc

C# ASP.NET MVC web application - I followed all the steps from https://blogs.iis.net/davidso/azurefile in order to be able to access my Azure location by unc.

My newly created local user is in the IISUSER Group and has the same username and pwd (storage key).

I then created an application in my website using a new APP Pool (integrated) w/said local user.

I ran the caspol command as well.

The issue I run into is when trying to do a `file.SaveAs`, I get an error

> Incorrect username or password

`Server.MapPath({application})` returns the correct unc path but doing a `Directory.Exists` won't locate the path.

When viewing the "connect as" with specified user in IIS I get no issues, additionally I can access the unc path directly from my local machine with same creds.

I tried going to the app pool of the application and set the user directly but no change there. Are there changes I need to make on the Website configuration that the application sits in? Prior to converting this to an application I initially had it configured as a virtual directory and got the same error.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the load user profile to "True" in the application pool:

[image]

try to set the azure user in iis anonymous authentication by clicking on the edit:

[image]